# How to use \begin{array} environment with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I want to insert several math equations in array form in a tikz node in beamer. However, I got the following error:  Missing $ inserted

The source code is:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[name-math] {
\[ 
\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
|X \cap Y| & \text{cardinality}\\
|X \cap Y|, \sum_{i \in X \cap Y} v_i & \text{cardinality-sum}\\
f(X, Y) & \text{general computation}
\end{array}\right.\]}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which packages need to be loaded in order to make your code (minimally) compilable.

Comment: Use `\(` and `\)`, not `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: You need a `text width` to be able to use display math. But just for an array or a `cases` there's no need for display math and inline math (`\( … \)`) (and possibly `\displaystyle`) is enough. If you load the `mathtools` package you can use the `cases*` environment that sets the second column in text mode without you having to use `\text`.

Answer (score 5):

With `\[...\]` you make display math, which is not meaningful inside a Ti*k*Z node.

Just use inline math mode, that is, `\(...\)`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Cases}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\(
  \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
  |X \cap Y| & \text{cardinality}\\
  |X \cap Y|, \sum_{i \in X \cap Y} v_i & \text{cardinality-sum}\\
  f(X, Y) & \text{general computation}
  \end{array}\right.
\)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {\(
  \begin{cases}
  |X \cap Y| & \text{cardinality}\\
  |X \cap Y|, \sum_{i \in X \cap Y} v_i & \text{cardinality-sum}\\
  f(X, Y) & \text{general computation}
  \end{cases}
\)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I suggest to use `cases`: alignment and spacing is much better.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works! Thanks~